# How do I fix this Invalid variance modifier error?:

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void checkTheCheckInterval(Func<in SqlConnection, in Random, in TextBox, out Boolean> myFunc) {

}
```

I get this build error:

error CS1960: Invalid variance modifier. Only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant.

The error appears on all the commas.

Comment: `private void checkTheCheckInterval(Func<SqlConnection, Random, TextBox,  Boolean> myFunc)`? Just removing all `in` and `out` which are about C# *covariance*, not parameters?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks! Post your answer and I'll pick it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid C#. Variance modifiers can only be used when you *declare* a generic delegate *type* or an interface. Here you *use* the delegate type `Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, out TResult>`.

When you *use* the type and specify *generic arguments* like `SqlConnection`, `Random` etc. for the *generic parameters* `T1`...`T3` and `TResult`, you cannot specifiy variance modifiers, as the variance is declared by `Func<...>`

```
private void checkTheCheckInterval(Func<SqlConnection, Random, TextBox, Boolean> myFunc)
{
}
```

---

This is the declaration of the type `Func<...>` (taken from [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,d6a8fafda0383fc5)):

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3);
```

Here the variance is declared and you cannot and don't need to change it when you use `Func<>`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to pass a lambda which takes 3 arguments (`SqlConnection`, `Random` and `TextBox`) and returns `Boolean` value:

```
private void checkTheCheckInterval(Func<SqlConnection, Random, TextBox, Boolean> myFunc) {

}
```